# Azure ML Two-Class Decision Forest causes Score Model Error 1000

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Can anybody explain to me why Two-Class Decision Forest causes Score Model Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: col: Invalid index: 1, expected bounds [0, 1)? My dataset is normalized, column names doesn't contains spaces...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the experiment and a sample of your data?